# Best implementation of robot state control

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i have a simple robot which different states:

- idle
- do something
- do something else
- ...

I wanted to change my states with some button inputs and every state has it own node.

I thought about a state machine with smach, but smach isn't under developing at the moment. Or can I use actionlib for that? I also found the package decision_making

What is the best approach to implement this in your experience? Or do you use something without ROS?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200602/best-implementation-of-robot-state-control/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

smach is probably the best option.  It's not currently under development, but it works well, and and covers exactly what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2015-01-09**:
Thank you for your answer. Do you have a example/tutorial for smach with catkin_make? I tried it with groovy but it didn't work http://answers.ros.org/question/200512/smach-groovy/